# Ambiguous use of subscript swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

In swift 2 this came up: Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

```
 var plistDict: NSDictionary?
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myTip", ofType: "plist") {
            plistDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
            let plistArray = plistDict!["tip"]
            let randV = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(plistArray!.count)))
        ------->>>>    let tipMessage = plistArray![randV] //error here???

                let tipAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Something...", message: tipMessage as? String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                tipAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
```

Answer (score 2):

When you get `plistArray` out of `plistDict`, it doesn't know what the type of element it is, so it considers it an `AnyObject?`. And because of that, it doesn't know how to deal with the subscript that you're giving it, because it doesn't know how to deal with subscripts for the `AnyObject` type. If you cast `plistDict!["tip"]` to the appropriate type when assigning it to `plistArray`, then it should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Something like this? let plistArray = plistDict!["tip"] as! NSArray
            let randV = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(plistArray!.count)))
      let tipMessage = plistArray[randV]

Comment: Yes, that looks about right. Though you should try to use implicitly unwrapped optionals less often, because it's not very safe.